# How to enable Windows firewall to log attempts to connect to closed (not listenting) ports?

Tags: windows

We have some servers with Windows firewall and logging enabled for dropped connections.

We observe that when we do a port scan with nmap, the log (pfirewall.log) only reports attempts to connect ports listening. Ports not listening are not reported, which makes it more difficult to detect a port scan.

What options are posible?

Comment: This looks like a logging config issue and not a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an unavoidable Windows feature. Only connections to opened ports are logged.

One can use netsh wfp for logging: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428146%28v=ws.10%29.aspx